# How to pass a key from parent JSON into #each loop in handlebars

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js, each

Following is the JSON over which I am iterating the `category` key using `#each` in handlebars.

**JSON -**

```
{ 
  title: "TEST TITLE", 
  body: "This is my first HANDLEBAR",
  category: [{name: 'Button 1', id: 111}, {name: 'Button 2', id: 111}]
}
```

**HANDLEBAR TEMPLATE -**

```
{{#each this.category}}
<button value="{{name}}">{{name}}</button>

{{this.title}}
{{/each}}
```

**OUTPUT -**

```
<button value="Button 1">Button 1</button>


<button value="Button 2">Button 2</button>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT -**

```
<button value="Button 1">Button 1</button>

TEST TITLE
<button value="Button 2">Button 2</button>
```

Let me know how can I reach to the expected output as `{{this.title}}` is not working.

Comment: @Rajesh No its not

Answer (score 0):

To access the parent key I need to do - `{{../title}}` and it will print the title then.